# Remove Roles Information from JWT token

Tags: java, jwt, keycloak

I am using keycloak for authentication for the application. I want to remove the realm access from JWT token generated by keycloak.

1. Is it a bad practice to have realm access (roles) ion JWT token?
2. Is there a way to remove realm access from JWT token generated by keycloak service?

Answer (score 2):

1. I may be wrong but I don't see this as a bad practice because the Token is signed. A client won't be able to change the content of the token payload without knowing your secret (The token signature would be false). Just be sure to check the token validity.
2. If you want to change the information provided in your token, you should have a look at the "Client Scope" section.

[image]

From there, you'll be able to change the content of your jwt token.

Comment: I tried this. But my token is not being validated from the keycloak service. Can you please suggest. Getting this ```RPT (Requesting Party Token) is not active, this response is returned instead: { "active": false }```

Comment: I replied to the 2 questions. I think it's another issue.. 
Unfortunately, without being able to see your configuration it will be hard to know what is misconfigured. Sorry.

Comment: I changed the configuration to not include the realm access in JWT token. Is there something else to be changed along with it?

Answer (score -2):

I think, it depends on your **security policies exist in your software boundary or environment**. We had a project that existing user or client roles inside JWT token introduced a major security issue by security analysts, although *we had launched it many times* in other critical environments.
By the way, some software frameworks do some ***proactive authorization checks*** by using roles coming inside JWT and so, make them **mandatory** for these kind of systems based their security design.

 So to wrap it up,

> Try enquiry security analysts of your deployment s environments about
> it.